# Connected webpart with grouping

Tags: 2007, list

I have connected two webparts together based on one field. The provider provides an ID value to consumer webpart, whose data gets filetered.

This filtering fails, when the grouping is applied on the provider webpart. The grouping is done on entirely different column and the column value being sent is still present in the view.

Any idea why it happens and any workarounds?

Comment: Does the grouping have paging on the provider web part?

Comment: Yes, it has default paging of 20

Comment: Can you tell me if the issue exists if the paging does not happen for a result? ie, even though the grouping exist, the results should come in a single page. Check if the issue exists that time.

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand. The result will appear on the consumer web part. Did you mean consumer in the original question ? The grouping exists in provider.....

Comment: sorry for the confusion. I have seen issues happening when grouping of web parts come with paging. When you browse along all the pages(0-20,20-40), the grouping breaks. I wanted you to check if the results are coming correctly, if the results in the providing web part appears within a page, here it should be less than 20 items within the grouping.